# Salesforce Package w/ external code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I've had some scripts that query sfdc and do some web scraping, ultimately pushing that data back into salesforce. i'd like to productize this a bit and get a managed package set up but am unsure where to start.

I'd need to build a native app where folks can interact but I need the code that I built(Python) to run externally.

Does anyone know of documentation or ideas on how to execute external code from Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

I have not published an app on the exchange, but I know you will need a Partner Account.  Info on getting one for free here:  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments

Consider hosting your Python app on Heroku.

Integration workbook: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_workbook/